# The method marshal(Object, Result) in the type Marshaller is not applicable for the arguments (T, File)

Tags: java, xml

i follow http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
file or (Result)file got error java.io.File cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.Result
what is the correct writing?

```
File file = new File(path);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass.getClass());
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

//output pretty printed
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(boject, file);
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.Result
    at martin.XMLObj.ConvertObjectToXML(XMLObj.java:26)
    at martin.Helloworld.main(Helloworld.java:100)
```

Original code

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(100);
customer.setName("mkyong");
customer.setAge(29);
XMLObj<Customer> XMLtool = new XMLObj<Customer>(Customer.class);
try {
    XMLtool.ConvertObjectToXML("c:\\file5.xml", customer);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

.

```
public class XMLObj<T> {
    final Class<T> typeParameterClass;
    public XMLObj(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }
    public void ConvertObjectToXML(String path, T boject)
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            //output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(boject, fs);
            fs.flush();
            fs.close();

            //jaxbMarshaller.marshal(boject, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getInstance().process_message(e.getMessage());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getInstance().process_message(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public T ConvertXMLToObject(String path)
    {
        //Convert XML to Object
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            if(file.exists())
            {
                JAXBContext jaxbContext;
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass.getClass());
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                T bobj = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(bobj);
                return bobj;
            }
            else
                Logger.getInstance().process_message("File not exist in ConvertObjectToXML");
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getInstance().process_message(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever read the API first?

The 2nd parameter of `Marshaller#marshal()` is NOT taking a File.

There are bunch of other overloads of `marshal()` that you can make use of, e.g. `marshall(Object, OutputStream)`.  How to write actually is something you should be able to figure out by yourself.

Comment: i believe example is correct, finally use jaxbMarshaller.marshal(boject, new FileOutputStream(file)); but the file is blank

Comment: i updated question with code, can you see why xml file blank after write

Comment: have you close or flush the stream? And, can you please only include relevant codes? your new piece of code is big and contains quite some irrelevant stuff

Comment: After add flush and close, still blank file

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a blank file due to the line

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass.getClass());
```

Change this to

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass);
```

The problem is that `typeParameterClass.getClass()` has type of class of `java.lang.Class` which will not be able to unmarshall a `Customer` object.